# Fetch numeric data in string with mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, collections, nosql

I would like to know how I can search for all data in mongodb in which the value is greater than or equal to 15,000, as this data is as a string and I don't know how to do this, as the gte function uses numeric fields. I am using aggregate to fetch the data..

Example of how the data is in the database:

```
  data_1: {
    assistance: 'US$ 60.000'
  },

  data_2: {
    assistance: 'US$ 35.000'
  },

  data_3: {
    assistance: 'US$ 15.000'
  }
}
```

The best I could do was search for elements by exact value

```
{ '$match': {'data': { $regex: /15.000/ } } }
```

Comment: I think it is a bad design to store numeric values as strings. Better convert them into number, then you can compare easily. Comparators like `$gte` also work on strings, however, the order is not numeric, of course. See [Comparison/Sort Order](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/v7.0/reference/bson-type-comparison-order/#std-label-bson-types-comparison-order)

Comment: Are the field names dynamic as well? Your example suggests so but the`$match` you've provided wouldn't work if so

Comment: Yes, they are dynamic. I did it like this just to give an example. I just need to filter the assistance field as if it were a number. With regex the way I put it, it can pull exactly the desired number, but I want to get something greater than or equal to the desired number.